# jQueryMobile: how to work with slider events?

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-mobile

I'm testing the [slider](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/forms/forms-slider.html) events in [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and I must been missing something.

page code is:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="slider">Input slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100"  />
</div>
```

and if I do:

```
$("#slider").data("events");
```

I get

```
blur, focus, keyup, remove
```

What I want to do is to **get the value once user release the slider handle**

and having a hook to the keyup event as

```
$("#slider").bind("keyup", function() { alert('here'); } );
```

does absolutely nothing :(

I must say that I **wrongly assumed** that jQueryMobile used [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) controls as it was my first thought, but now working deep in the events I can see this is not the case, only in terms of CSS Design.

> **What can I do?**

jQuery Mobile Slider [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.forms.slider.js) can be found on [Git](https://github.com) if it helps anyone as well a **test page** can be found at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/idobu3/edit)

---

As I understand, the `#slider` is the textbox with the value, so I would need to hook into the slider handle as the generated code for this slider is:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
    <label for="slider" class="ui-input-text ui-slider" id="slider-label">Input slider:</label>
    <input data-type="range" max="100" min="0" value="0" id="slider" name="slider" class="ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-c ui-slider-input" />
    <div role="application" class="ui-slider  ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all">
        <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" href="#" data-theme="c" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="54" aria-valuetext="54" title="54" aria-labelledby="slider-label" style="left: 54%;">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
                <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and checking the events in the handler anchor I get only the `click` event

```
$("#slider").next().find("a").data("events");
```

---

**Fix**

From Ivan answer, we just need:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="slider">Input slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100"  />
</div>
```

and then

```
$(document).bind("pagecreate", function(event, ui) {

    $('#slider').siblings('.ui-slider').bind('tap', function(event, ui){ makeAjaxChange($(this).siblings('input')); });
    $('#slider').siblings('.ui-slider a').bind('taphold', function(event, ui){ makeAjaxChange($(this).parent().siblings('input')); 

});

function makeAjaxChange( elem ) { 
    alert(elem.val()); 
}
```

**Thank you** Ivan for the heads up.

Comment: You found exactly the same problem as I a week ago. jQMobile although swore they work on top of jQuery UI, this is not the case whatsoever.Turns out, jQuery mobile widgets just looks like UI widgets, but do not follow same UI concept of providing an interface for control like specific hooks and properties except for specific html attributes which is IMHO pretty far away from useful and potentially harming html markup.

Comment: A solution similar to Ivan's: [jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-execute-javascript-code-when-finger-is-lifted-from-a-slider) That's the only one worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution to your problem is to hookup handlers on tap and taphold events.
Tap is hooked on div element of slider, while taphold is hooked on a element (slider control button).

HTML markup of slider:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br" data-role="fieldcontain" id="element-boravak3">
     <label class="ui-input-text ui-slider" id="boravak3-label" for="boravak3">strop</label>
    <input class="ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-c ui-slider-input" name="boravak3" id="boravak3" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-type="range">
<!-- this is code that jQMobile generates -->
    <div role="application" class="ui-slider  ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all">
        <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" href="#" data-theme="c" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuetext="0" title="0" aria-labelledby="boravak3-label" style="left: 0%;">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
                <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#' + id).slider();
$('#' + id).siblings('.ui-slider').bind('tap', function(){ makeAjaxChange($(this).siblings('input')); });
$('#' + id).siblings('.ui-slider a').bind('taphold', function(){ makeAjaxChange($(this).parent().siblings('input')); });
```

Function makesAjaxChange(elem) makes the update to the server.
There is one other thing to note here, changing value in input field does not updates server so you have to bind function to change event of input element. Also you must pay attention that by doing this every slider control move will trigger input element change so you have to workaround that too.

This is why jQuery Mobile is NOT jQuery UI for mobile devices. You dont have these things sorted out and must do them yourself.

I hope this helps.

EDIT:
I forgot to explain why tap on div.ui-slider and taphold on a.ui-slider-handle.
div.ui-handler tap is for click/tap event when user just clicks or taps a finger on slidebar. a.ui-slider-handle tabhold is after user was moving with mouse or finger left/right down the slidebar and released it.

Ivan

Comment: It's a great solution, thank you for the help Ivan! I would love to have the full control in JQMobile just like we have in JQueryUI :) - P.S. You don't need `$('#' + id).slider();` if you use the normal jQuery Mobile code as the simple input `<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100"  />`

Comment: I know I don't need .slider() invoked, but this is code I'm still working on... f.i. I still don't use jQMobile pages etc...

Answer (score 9):

Try this code:

```
$( "#slider-1").on('slidestop', function( event ) {
   var slider_value=$("#slider-1").slider().val();
   alert('Value: '+slider_value);
});
```

I hope this work for you

Answer (score 2):

Based on @VTWood's solution; here's a generic 'fix' for all jQuery-Mobile 1.1 sliders so they dispatch `start` and `stop` events at the appropriate times.  You just need to drop this code into your page once to patch up all future sliders.

```
$(document).on({
    "mousedown touchstart": function () {
        $(this).siblings("input").trigger("start");
    },
    "mouseup touchend": function () {
        $(this).siblings("input").trigger("stop");
    }
}, ".ui-slider");
```

In a nutshell, it binds an event listener to the document object which listens for both `mousedown` and `touchstart` events triggered from `.ui-slider` elements.  Once triggered the handler function will find the `input` element which sits alongside the `.ui-slider` control that was clicked and trigger a `start` event.  You can consume this like so:

```
$("#my-slider").on("start", function () { 
    console.log("User has started sliding my-slider!");
});

$("#my-slider").on("stop", function (event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    console.log("User has finished sliding my slider, its value is: " + value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a much simpler solution to this problem.  Using this code, you can retrofit start and stop events onto the slider.

```
$('.ui-slider').live('mousedown', function(){$('#'+id).trigger('start');});
$('.ui-slider').live('mouseup', function(){$('#'+id).trigger('stop');});
$('.ui-slider').live('touchstart', function(){$('#volumeSlider').trigger('start');});
$('.ui-slider').live('touchend', function(){$('#volumeSlider').trigger('stop');});
```

Comment: I think you mean deprecated. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there's some issues in using Ivan's solution. If you drag the slider, pause for a while (not lifting the mouse button) and keep on dragging the slider the taphold -event won't be triggered anymore.

By adding the vmouseup and mouseup events in to the slider div you get an improvement but the slider still fails to trigger the event if the mouse cursor is moved away from above the slider.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="range" id="player-slider" value="25" min="0" max="100"/>

$( "#player-slider" ).bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
    alert ("changed!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just catch the event when the slider is released (most probably to optimize ajax requests).

This worked for me:

```
var slider = $('#my_slider');
//as the answer from @nskeskin you have to remove the type range from your input on the html code
slider.slider({create:function(){
    //maybe this is too much hacking but until jquery provides a reference to this...
    $(this).next().children('a').bind('vmouseup', yourOnChangeCallback);
}
});
```

Also this prevents that you add events when the control is not yet initialized (or created), so waiting for the create event is a bit more correct I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#slider').next().children('a').bind('taphold', function () {
        $('#slider').live("change", function (event, ui) {
          //do these.....
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and easy way you can check below link. you will get code for all mobile devices.

http://trentrichardson.com/2011/11/11/jquery-ui-sliders-and-touch-accessibility/