# Get value while dragging the slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile

How do I get the value of the slide while I drag the slide?

I tried but it did not work:

```
$("#slider").slider({
   slide : function() { 
        alert($("#slider").val());
   }
});
```

Comment: can you provide the slider in question?

Comment: Is the jquery mobile slide.. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/transitions/slider/

Answer (score 0):

As written [here](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event), to get the value you need to use `stop` and not `slide` to get the value after interaction is stopped

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    alert($(this).val());
  }
});
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hFAy4/)

Comment: I'm needing to get the value while dragging. Is it possible?

Comment: you can use this answer for that since Jquery mobile ui dont support that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583083/jquerymobile-how-to-work-with-slider-events

Comment: I solved my problem with this topic you referred me. Thank you.