# Getting the value from a jQuery Mobile slider in 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying get a value from a jQuery Mobile slider in 1.4.2 so that I can write in code for the user to adjust the volume. I've tried the exact code from all of the answers posted on
[jQueryMobile: how to work with slider events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583083/jquerymobile-how-to-work-with-slider-events?rq=1)
but none of them seem to work anymore.

Here is a codepen showing the results of the accepted answer; any ideas how to get it working? Thanks!

http://codepen.io/KireniaV/pen/LbADc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just handle the "change" event on the slider:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#settings", function() {
    $('#slider').on("change", function(){
      alert($(this).val());
    });                                                                              
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! That was much easier than I was making it.